# Collapse is not working in navabar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Exactly i want to create like this]

collapse not working tried so many way.

I create a navabar in bootstrap using some class or id to show default data, when i collapse my browser it is not working. Right Button or ul li position also not accurate in my code or example shown in displayed image which were above side in my post kindly resolve this problem.

```css
nav{
 display: block; 
}
nav #ss-logo{
 height: 62px;
    width: 206px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
 right: 32px;
}
nav .btn-primary{
 background-color: #2eb066;
    /**padding: 15px 15px;**/
    border-color: #2eb066;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #02a15e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 18px 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 279px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav #questions{
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  letter-spacing: -1.2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height:30px;
  color: #FFF;
}
nav #login {
  color:#2eb066;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height:30px
}
nav li a{
  color: #FFF;
}
nav li{
  padding:0px 10px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assingment_bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<nav id="top-nav" class="full-width navbar navbar-inverse dark-bg navbar-toggleable-md">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" name="toggle_button" id="toggle_button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my_navbar" area-expanded="false">
       <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img id="ss-logo" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50" alt="boots_image"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my_navbar"> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto color_one">
       <li class="nav-item active">
        <a id="login" class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-lock"> Log in</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="questions" class="nav-link" href="#"> Questions? (877) 442-1693</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Try Free for 30 Days</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
```

Comment: have you added "meta viewport" tag in your html

Comment: Yes, i added in my HTML

Comment: it is working fine check this link ----  https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/jLrRjW

Comment: It's not working Chandra.

Comment: check for any console errors in browser

Comment: i think you are using bootstrap3 html code for bootstrap 4 css.. check it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/6a7vg5nn/2/

```css
nav{
 display: block; 
}
nav #ss-logo{
 height: 62px;
    width: 206px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
 right: 32px;
}
nav .btn-primary{
 background-color: #2eb066;
    /**padding: 15px 15px;**/
    border-color: #2eb066;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #02a15e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 18px 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 279px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav #questions{
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  letter-spacing: -1.2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height:30px;
  color: #FFF;
}
nav #login {
  color:#2eb066;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height:30px
}
nav li a{
  color: #FFF;
}
nav li{
  padding:0px 10px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my_navbar" aria-controls="my_navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="ss-logo" src="logo-white.png" alt="boots_image" /></a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my_navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right mr-auto color_one">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-lock"> Log in</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Questions? (877) 442-1693</a>
      </li> 
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item navbar-right">
       <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Try Free for 30 Days</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you explain what was the issue?

Comment: I didn't use your code, rather I wrote new code & added your required content to that.... Issue may be **<span class="fa fa-lock">** not closing the span tag....

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your .navbar-header in HTML

HTML

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my_navbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    </div>
```

[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/jLrRjW?editors=1000)